# Display films from Swapi API but receiving [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, async-await

**So what I am trying to accomplish is the page should show each character and film they were in. Below the character names, instead of the `[object Promise]`, it should show the films they were in. But when I pass the function `get_movies(films)` to `p` tag I get `[object Promise]`.**

```
const fetch_data = async () => {
  axios
    .get("https://swapi.dev/api/people")
    .then((res) => {
       people(res.data.results);
     
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Ooops!There is an error with fetching the data", err);
 
    });
};

let people = (data) => {
  data.map((person) => {
   //create films tags
    films = person.films;    
    
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    let linkText = document.createTextNode( get_movies(films));
    p.appendChild(linkText);
 
    document.body.appendChild(p);

      //create names with their info 
    let mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
    
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "Name: " + person.name + " Hair Color:  " + person.hair_color + "  Birth Year:" + "  DOB: " +  person.birth_year;   
    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
    mainContainer.appendChild(p); 

   });
};
 
 
//fetch api from films array 
let get_movies = async (movies)=>{
    return movies.map(movie => {   
    axios
    .get(movie)
    .then((res) => {
        newRes = JSON.stringify(res)
        return showMovies(res)
    })

    })
}

// show each movie from the api array 
let showMovies = (movies =>{
    let eachMovie = movies.data.title
    return eachMovie
  
    })
 
fetch_data();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsnm9jv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there and welcome to StackOverflow!

The `async` keyword in JS only applies to the function it's on. If you use closures (for example in a `.map` call, or call other functions, those will need to handle Promises themselves or be async, too.

```js
const fetch_data = () => {
  return axios
    .get("https://swapi.dev/api/people")
    .then(res => {
      // This return is important!
      return people(res.data.results);
    })
};
```

Be aware though, that you need to use async functions or use promises in the other functions that fetch data, too. Therefore I return the `people` function and change it to be an `async` function.

You mixed between `async` functions and `.then` usage. Usually it's good to stick to using `await` in `async` functions. I attached a cleaned up code sandbox at the end.

Side note: a common practice to start an asynchronous task in JS is, to attach the `.catch` directly to the top-level function call:

```js
fetch_data()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Ooops!There is an error with fetching the data", err);
  });
```

As I said above, your `people` function has to be async, so it can fetch data. Since `get_movies` is `async` and is called inside the closure in `.map`, I made the closure `async` and used `Promise.all` to make sure fetching the movies for each person runs as expected. Crucially the `await get_movies(films)` is the important part. An `async` function returns a promise. To get to the underlying value you want to display, you have to `await` the result of the `get_movies(films)` call.

```js
const people = async (data) => {
  await Promise.all(data.map(async (person) => {
   //create films tags
    films = person.films;    
    
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    let linkText = document.createTextNode(await get_movies(films));
    p.appendChild(linkText);
 
    document.body.appendChild(p);

      //create names with their info 
    let mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
    
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "Name: " + person.name + " Hair Color:  " + person.hair_color + "  Birth Year:" + "  DOB: " +  person.birth_year;   
    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
    mainContainer.appendChild(p); 

   }));
};
```

Because we `.map` to create promises, the data fetching happens in parallel. Since the individual calls to `axios.get(movie)` and therefore `get_movies(films)` can resolve in any order, the order of the UI elements will also be random. To solve this, fetch the data first, and await all of the results. Then in the next step, iterate over the data to create the nodes.

```js
const people = async (data) => {
  const personData = await Promise.all(data.map(async (person) => {
   //create films tags
    films = person.films;

    return { ...person, films: await get_movies(films) };
  }))
    
  personData.forEach((person) => {
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    let linkText = document.createTextNode(person.films);
    p.appendChild(linkText);
 
    document.body.appendChild(p);

      //create names with their info 
    let mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
    
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "Name: " + person.name + " Hair Color:  " + person.hair_color + "  Birth Year:" + "  DOB: " +  person.birth_year;   
    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
    mainContainer.appendChild(p); 

   });
};
```

With `return { ...person, films: await get_movies(films) };` I create a copy of the person object, overwriting `films` with the result of the fetched films. I do this because we need the properties of `person` as well as the fetched `films` in the next step.

The `Promise.all` ensures that all network requests have finished. And since we used `.map` the data is in the same order as in the original array.

The `get_movies` function uses `.map` but doesn't return anything. If you use curly braces (`{`) there is no implicit return value, you need to use `return` explicitly. Just as before you're returning a promise from axios in the `.map`, which means you get an array of promises. With `Promise.all` you wait for all promises / network requests to resolve and then convert it to an array of values.

```js
//fetch api from films array 
let get_movies = async (movies) => {
  return await Promise.all(movies.map(movie => {
    return axios
      .get(movie)
      .then((res) => {
        newRes = JSON.stringify(res)
        return showMovies(res)
      })
  }))
}
```

I took the liberty of cleaning this up a little and putting it in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-to-promise-usage-zki6d).

Hope this helps. If you have any more questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hi Moritz, thank you so much for the detailed explanation and for providing the code sandbox. I really appreciate it. 
One more question, since the films arrays from api has also additional information such as realease date and list of characters that appear in specific film. Is this possible to display that information on a different html page? Do I need to create another div and after receiving this data, show that film name along with some details about that film such as the release date on films.html file? 
Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a new question. It's unclear what you mean by "different html page". If it's a different page you need to fetch the data again. Please open a follow up question with details on what you want to do, and I'll look into it. If you liked my detailed explanation I'd appreciate you'd give it an upvote, too. :)

Comment: I will, thanks again! I did upvote but because my reputation is below 15 it did not let my upvote! I wish I could!

Comment: here is my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68122518/how-to-display-results-of-api-on-new-page